# Dynamic chart that is updated each time step in paraview

Tags: paraview, post-processing, openfoam

I am using paraview to post process OpenFOAM results. I'm working on an open channel case. In addition to OpenFOAM run results, I've post-processed the flow rate through the inlet. Now I have a file that contains the flow rate in each time step.

So, in paraview, I want to plot the free surface in one render view and in another one I want to plot a dynamic chart for flow rate vs. time where the chart is only built up to the current time step.

If that's not possible in paraview, what is the better alternative that can create such chart and works with OpenFOAM?

Similar example to clarify the idea:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jnf9EGuHiV0

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for "Plot Data Over Time" Filter.

You can find it in `Filters -> Alphabetical -> Plot Data Over Time`